# How to make images not duplicate with Cloudinary Image Upload using node npm

Tags: cloudinary

How can I overwrite images I upload to cloudinary so I do not duplicate and have multiple images that are all exactly the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have an image called "sample_image" in your account and you want to upload another image with the same name, you can simply upload it while setting the `public_id` to "sample_image" and add the `overwrite` parameter.
Also, you probably want to purge the old image from the CDN to make sure you're delivering the newest version, so set the `invalidate` flag to `true` in the upload call as well.

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload('my_image.jpg', function(result) { console.log(result) }, 
                       { public_id: "sample_image", overwrite:true, invalidate,true });
```

Comment: Any idea how to quickly wipe my entire account of all public_ids ?

Comment: You can use the Admin API to delete resources. You can either delete all or by a specific criteria.
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#delete_resources

Comment: It's really sad to make client code responsible for duplication prevention. Would be nice to have cloudinary built-in images comparison (not just returning a description like md5 and phash).

Comment: @SerG Cloudinary has this option by automatically setting the public_id as the resource's etag thus preventing any duplications.